# Flutter: How to restrict user to select item accordingly in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `flutter_multi_select_items` for multiple items selected from an array of items in JSON format. It is working before but I will like to restrict users to only select items in the order from right to left and not jump to any item to pick the next. For example if I have an array `[1,2,3,4]` I will like user to select in order `1->2->3->4` only and not pick like `1->3->2->4` etc.

My code:

```
MultiSelectContainer(
    itemsPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
    textStyles: const MultiSelectTextStyles(
    textStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', 
     fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,)),
     showInListView: true,
     listViewSettings: ListViewSettings( scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
     separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const SizedBox(
      width: 10,)),
     items: List.generate(dataSchedule == null ? 0 : dataSchedule.length,
     (index) => MultiSelectCard(value: dataSchedule[index]['time_slot'], label: dataSchedule[index]['time_slot'],)),
onChange: (allSelectedItems, selectedItem) { })
```

Below is what my array return looks like:

```
["16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00"]
```

And I will like selection to be from `16:00 to 17:00 to 18:00 to 19:00 to 20:00 to 21:00`

From the above code `allSelectedItems` is for an array of items selected and `selectedItem` is just for a single item selected. If there is any part of clarification needed please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share a complete example with Array list "dataSchedule".

Comment: I just add it as requested

Comment: I didn't get what you explained above @AndreasMüller

Comment: Sorry I miss unsterstood what you are trying to do. Forget about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by applying some logic to achieve this. Since I can't get `index` inside `onchanged` I added to my `value:` the index so I can get the index value of each select, then I later removed the extra value from the value and leave only the `index` value and then get the previous select value and current selected value. Finally, I used `if` statement to check if the current select minus 1 is equal to the previous select then it is correct or else not. My final code is as below:

```
MultiSelectContainer(
                                                    controller: controllerMultipleSelect,
                                                    itemsPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                   
                                                    showInListView: true,
                                                    listViewSettings: ListViewSettings(
                                                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                        separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const SizedBox(
                                                          width: 10,
                                                        )),

                                                    items: List.generate(dataSchedule == null ? 0 : dataSchedule.length,
                                                            (index) => MultiSelectCard(
                                                              value: index.toString() +"-"+ dataSchedule[index]['time_slot'], label: dataSchedule[index]['time_slot'],)),
                                                    onChange: (allSelectedItems, selectedItem) {


                                                      if(allSelectedItems.length>1) {

                                                        var lst = allSelectedItems[allSelectedItems.length - 2];
            

                                                        var pos = lst.toString().lastIndexOf('-');

        String previousResult = (pos != -1)? lst.substring(0, pos): lst;
        var pos1 = selectedItem.toString().lastIndexOf('-');

        String currResult = (pos1 != -1)? selectedItem.substring(0, pos1): selectedItem;

                                                       if(int.parse(currResult)-1  == int.parse(previousResult)){
                                                         debugPrint("Correct order");
                                                       }else{


                                                         debugPrint("Incorrect order");


                                                       }

                                                      }


                                                    })
```